# Solution to second order difference equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

A similar question has been answered at [Second-order difference equation solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3580370/second-order-difference-equation-solution?r=SearchResults)

However I'm not entirely convinced by the answers. I'm wondering how to explain convincingly to an undergraduate class as to why we "guess" or "assume" an exponential solution.

Just saying that we are taking this guess because the first order solution is also of an exponential form doesn't cut it, in my opinion. Is there a reasonably simple explanation?

Comment: What's not convincing about multiplication by matrix or forming the generating function?

Comment: Could you elaborate or provide a reference? None of the texts I'm following talk about this. Also, this is not a pure mathematics course, but a mathematics for economics course.

Comment: Have you actually read the answers there?